# Non Ascii character error when using compiled code

Tags: python

I have a python code which runs perfectly and I compiled it using py_compile.compile. The compile operation also worked nicely without any errors.

However, when I use this pyc file I get an error like

```
File "E:/tech/tech.pyc", line 1
    SyntaxError: Non-ASCII character '\xf3' in file E:/tech/tech.pyc on line 1, but no encoding declared; see http://www.python.org/peps/pep-0263.html for details
```

My question is how do I debug this error? The first line in my script is import os. I tried using

```
#!/usr/bin/python
```

It does not help either. Any suggestions on how this can be debugged?

Comment: Do you have any 'accent' characters in there at all, in any comments?

Comment: Did you try adding the encoding as per [PEP 0263](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0263/)

Comment: Apparently you handle Unicode characters in some routines that can handle only ASCII.

Answer (score 2):

You're doing *something* wrong. Please show your code. `'\xf3'` looks a lot like the pyc magic number to me (assuming you're using python 2.7):

```
>>> import imp
>>> imp.get_magic()
'\x03\xf3\r\n'
```

Are you trying to compile a pyc file (as if it were python source code)?